# Should a variable be declared before it is used as an argument in a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Example:

```js
var num;

function mySquare(num) {
  var sq = num * num;  
}
```

Is var num statement necessary or that statement can be neglected?

Comment: It is not necessary, you can return the value as well. `function mySquare(num) { return num*num; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you specific case, the statement `var num;` is useless. It won't even be used.

When you declare a function, the arguments represent local variables that are created specifically for the function block.

Answer (score 0):

num is a local variable inside function mySquare so you can ignore var num;

Answer (score 0):

function parameters will be declared and initialized before passing them into the function.

```
function a(helloWorld) {
    console.log(helloWorld)
}
a("test") //test
var b = "hallo welt"
a(b) //hallo welt 
a(c) //undefined
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `num` as the name of an argument in the parameter list, you have already declared it as a local variable. Explicitly adding `var num` inside the function would be redundant and JSLint would warn you that you are redeclaring `num` if you tried.

Explicitly adding `var num` outside the function would create a global variable with the same name… that you never use. This is also redundant.